# Center image based on parent when parent is a link

Tags: html, css

The current code I have worked on below fades out the text and instead reveals an image..

HTML

```
<div class="rightNavContainer">
  <a class="characterFade" href="#">
    <div class="fadeMe">Characters</div>
    <img class="characterLogo" src="https://openclipart.org/image/2400px/svg_to_png/103027/1293960051.png" alt="logo"></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.rightNavContainer {
  margin-top: 28px;
  width: 100%;
}

.rightNavContainer a {
  position: relative;
  margin-left:25%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  text-shadow: 2px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.fadeMe {
  position: relative;
  margin-left:25%;
}

.rightNavContainer .characterFade .fadeMe {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
.rightNavContainer .characterFade .fadeMe:hover {
  opacity: 0.0;
  transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
}

.characterLogo {
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -1em;
  margin-left: 10.6em;
}

.rightNavContainer .characterFade .fadeMe:hover ~ .characterLogo {
  display: block;
  -webkit-animation: fadein 3s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

This is the fiddle..https://jsfiddle.net/m8pa9u1k/23/

The problem with this is that I have hardcoded the margin-left: 10.6em; inside .characterLogo which puts the image in the center for now but if I was to change the dimensions of the screen the image is no longer in the center. Is there a way to always keep the image in the center of the link tag characterFade? aka center based on the parent class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this amendment to your fiddle:

```
.rightNavContainer a {
  position: relative;
  margin-left:25%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  text-shadow: 2px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  display: inline-block;
}

.characterLogo {
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: -1em;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m8pa9u1k/30/

Setting `margin: 0 auto;` sets 0 for top and bottom margins, but the browser picks the margins for left and right automatically. It's a commonly used technique for centering some elements.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin

Seeing as you're using relative positioning, I've removed the -1em top margin and replaced it with `top: -1em`. I think it makes it a bit clearer what the intention is.

Also, the width of your `a` was full width because the div is a block element. Changing it to `inline-block` causes the browser to calculate the width based in its actual content. It might have been better to use a `span` here, because it is an inline element, which are better suited to the contents of other inline elements.

Let me know if something isn't clear in my answer.

Comment: `.fadeMe {
  position: relative;
  margin-left:25%;
}`
I also removed this code from there it was messing up the centering.

Comment: I wondered about that. It's always best to keep your styles as trim and specific as possible, to avoid unwanted side-effects in the style of related elements.